# Is it normal to be terminated on the second day of the job?

Tags: termination

This is my first time as a contractor employee for a large biomedical company. Note, I had a face to face interview with the hiring manager for a good 1 hour and they offered me a position and I gladly accepted the position. I put in my two weeks at my old direct to hire job and decided to go for the oppurtunity at the company. On my first hire date on December 6, 2017, the IT guy was out of state and I could not access to my training materials such as OSHA, Lab safety guidelines, Bottling Control and etc. With that being said, I was not allowed to touch anything or performed any other tasks due to corporate rules, which I totally understand. The hiring manager decided to call IT and tried to get this situation resolved. Hiring manager decided to print out packets for me to read for the time being. I read a million packets until the day was over. The next day, I showed up to work, and I still did not have access to knowledge connection. The hiring manager was made well aware about this situation and she had decided to print out more packets for me to read as well. My coworker was aware of the situation and had told me that there was not anything else for me to do nor could I touch anything since my training process was not done.

At 4:30 P.M. the hiring manager had asked to see the key fob and told me she were to give it back to me. She took it the key fob and I waited around 4:41 P.M. for the fob to be returned back to me so I can enter the building for the next day of work. However, after that, my coworker told me that sometimes, hiring manager keeps the key fob for a while just to test it out but the coworker did offer me to let me into the building by giving out her phone number to me. I left around 4:41 P.M. 20 minutes into the drive home, I got a phone call from the recruited stating that I have been terminated and the recruiter wanted to find out why I was terminated. The recruiter had told me that the hiring manager had said that my speed for testing was too slow and I could not work in that Quality Manufacturing Department.

Is it normal for a hiring manager to treat contractors employees like this? 
A cut-throat termination without warning, seems unreasonable, and the reasoning for this termination is illogical. I haven't even had the ability to test any samples or products since I haven't completed any of my training. Can a hiring manager terminate a contractor employee after two days?

Comment: "Is this normal" and "can they do this" are two different questions; the latter being a legal one that depends on the contract you signed.

Comment: I signed for a three month contract.

Comment: Will depend on what your contract says then. Ultimately this type of thing absolutely sucks but there's generally not much you can realistically do about it. Keep in mind that being hired after a single hour-long interview is already a red flag in most cases, though it could be on the level for short-term stuff like this.

Comment: Contract says 12/5/2016 to March, Was filling in for a maternity person. The contract didn't really say much other than just fulfilling the job duties. However, I did sign a contract that I cannot sue them in any way shape or form. Smh, that was another red flag I should have seen. This is all new to me. Im usually a direct hire person. Thanks guys.

Comment: Not normal at all, in fact it sounds totally absurd.  They fired you for not doing a job quickly, a job that you had been prevented from ever starting?  They terminated you but didn't even tell you, they told the recruiter?  Nothing about this sounds normal to me.

Comment: @upallnight Yes, they told the recruiter over the phone. They didn't even pull me to the side or even criticized me or critique me. Most hiring managers or managers would pull you in the office and have a chit-chat with you and explain what you are doing wrong and what needs to be corrected. However, none of that happen. The recruiter tried to reach out to corporate but corporate tried to reach out to hiring manager and hiring manager stands firm on her decision. I was in shocked. Two days into the job and I didn't even start.

Comment: There was almost certainly a clause in your contract that gave them this option. It's not necessarily "normal", but that doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: @doritostyle, Alrighty thank you, I will go back and try to read that contract and see if I can find anything, perhaps I signed something that I didn't read and it could have been my fault, but good point tho, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I see a couple of possibilities here, neither of which I'd normally regard as very likely, but what's happened has happened:

- For some reason, the hiring manager decided they didn't like your face. Maybe you said something wrong. Maybe you wore the wrong colour clothes. Maybe they weren't even supposed to be hiring a new employee in the first place. Rather than explaining to their hierarchy all that, it's easier for hiring manager just to say "they were too slow".
- Someone, maybe the hiring manager, maybe IT, screwed up and didn't have the resources available to get you working when you started. Again rather than explaining why they've just paid an employee to do nothing for 2+ days, easier just to fabricate an excuse and make the problem "go away".

Obviously, neither of these are good reasons - but unfortunately, there's not going to be anything you can do about it either. Even if you could prove your version of events to be correct, you don't have any employment rights after 2 days of work, so yes, they can just sack you. It's bonkers, but sometimes the world is bonkers.

Comment: +1 and I would add, be sure to talk to your recruiter about this... An employer (most likely) CAN let a contractor go after 2 days, but it SHOULD hurt their reputation among recruiters and contractors.

Answer (score 8):

Answer from Kendall is good.

Another scenario is that you are collateral damage.  Someone is tired of having to pay people for 2+ days before getting them on line and you were the sacrificial example.

Comment: I can't imagine why this answer was downvoted. It is perfectly plausible that the hiring manager is fighting with IT, and wasting a contractor is just a move in their little political game.